# GIT - Isolar nova feature do branch master em um novo branch e resetar o branch master.

Tags: git, versionamento

Criei uma feature nova no branch master e gostaria de isolar ela em um novo branch.

E também, após criar o novo branch, gostaria de resetar meu branch local master para o branch remote master.

Criei este novo local branch, que acaba sendo uma cópia do branch local master (já incluindo minha feature), agora não entendi muito bem como faço para resetar somente o meu local master para ficar exatamente igual ao remote master.

Preciso fazer isto para poder commitar e fazer push do master sem que altere a aplicação em produção com esta nova feature, que ainda não está concluída.

Espero ter sido claro, que o meu objetivo é somente dar um reset no master e não nos demais.

Obrigado.

Comment: Você efetuou algum commit no master com essas alterações?

Comment: Ainda não. Comecei a desenvolver essa feature e não commitei mais. Foi um erro não ter isolado em um novo branch (por isso que queria fazer agora). Meu branch remote master não tem nada referente a esta alteração.

Comment: Então basta você efetuar um `git checkout -b feature` para criar um novo *branch* com as features a partir do master e commitar daí. Quando retornar ao `branch master` ele estará conforme o `remote master`.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade, não compreendi como o meu master local vai ficar igual ao remote (retornando ao estado do remote master). Seria porque ao commitar somente o branch da feature o local master irá perder as alterações? Realmente não compreendi esta parte.

Comment: Dá uma lida na resposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caso você não tenha efetuado qualquer `commit` no seu *branch master*, você pode efetuar o `git checkout -b feature` para que seja criado um novo *branch* com as alterações efetuadas.

Com isso o seu *branch master* estará conforme o *branch remote* pois todas as alterações efetuadas pertencerão ao *branch feature*.

Para você entender, veja a simulação no [learngitbranching](http://learngitbranching.js.org) com os seguintes comandos:

1. `git branch feature`
2. `git checkout feature`
3. `git commit`

Um outro exemplo mostrando um commit no *branch master* após o *feature*
v
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito. Era exatamente isto que eu precisava fazer.